# Добавить свою библиотеку (system/library) в Opencart 2.3

Tags: php, opencart

Создал файл `<root>/system/library/superlibrary.php`:

```
  class SuperLibrary {
       public function someMethod() {
       }
  }
```

Но если в файле `catalog/controller/common/header.php` пишу: `$this->SuperLibrary->someMethod();`, то получаю ошибку:

> Call to a member function someMethod() on null

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно подключить библиотеку в opencart 2.3?

Comment: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-custom-library-in-opencart--cms-25173

Comment: https://webkul.com/blog/creating-own-library-in-opencart/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58018504/how-to-include-my-custom-library-in-opencart-3

Comment: Если передаёте в метод какие-либо аргументы, то один из них на момент вызова может быть null. Тогда получается такой  фатал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `system/framework.php` добавить:

```
$registry->set('superlib', new SuperLibrary());
```

Вызывать `$this->superlib->someMetod();`

Comment: Для ОС 2.3 так: $registry->set('superlib', new SuperLibrary()); Но в целом то что нужно, спасибо!

Comment: очепятался, исправил, спасибо.